# how to use cmake to compile modern c++ project code

Tags: c++, cmake

here's my source code directory structure.

```
some project
    libs
        mylib1
            ...
        3rdlibs1
            ...
    apps
        myapp1
            ...
```

My requirments are as follows:

- 3rdlibs1 should be compiled when using command. like "cmake -G ...".
- 3rdlibs1 should be compiled as static library.
- mylib1 should be modular.
- mylib1 depends on 3rdlibs.
- myapp depends on mylib1, and it should only link to mylib1. It shouldn't depends on 3rdlibs or system libraries.

Can you give me some sample code. I know ExternalProject_Add can help me to compile 3rdlibs. But I really don't know how to do it.
I think other people may also be interesting to this question.

Comment: `cmake` is not going to compile. It is going to create the necessary build configuration files depending on your build system (make, visual studio solutions, ninja) etc.

Comment: What is the problem you're dealing with? Have you tried something or you hope us to create all the cmake file for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you have all your sources in single file system tree, it is better to use `add_subdirectory` than `ExternalProject`. `ExternalProject` is for projects which are truly external, e.g. on remote server or VCS repository. Unlike `add_subdirectory` which can create target of any type, `ExternalProject` can create only UTILITY target, similar to `add_custom_target` command. UTILITY targets have limitations, e.g. you can not use them in `target_link_libraries` command. Using `add_subdirectory` is much simpler.
Top-level:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project("some_project")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(libs/3rdlibs1)
add_subdirectory(libs/mylib1)
add_subdirectory(apps/myapp1)
```

App:

```
project("myapp1")

set(SRC_FILES ...)
add_executable(myapp1 ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(myapp1 PRIVATE mylib1)
```

Lib. As I understand from your description, 3rdlibs1 is optional dependency of mylib1. Otherwise, how can myapp use mylib1 without 3rdlibs1?

```
project("mylib1")

option(THIRD_LIBS_SUPPORT "description" OFF)

set(SRC_FILES ...)
add_library(mylib1 STATIC ${SRC_FILES})
#PUBLIC means that both mylib1 and its dependents use the headers
target_include_directories(mylib1 PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

if(THIRD_LIBS_SUPPORT)
    #PUBLIC means that 3rdlibs1 will be linked to mylib1 dependents
    target_link_libraries(mylib1 PUBLIC 3rdlibs1)
    target_compile_definitions(mylib1 PUBLIC -DTHIRD_LIBS_SUPPORT)
endif()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. However, you solution is not exactly fit my problem. Supposes, I have a 3rdlib named opencv which is a popular library for image processing. And mylib depents it. However, I don't want my  app to link it. I just want to link mylib.  That's good because when I give mylib to other people, I just need to give them mylib. I don't have to compile opencv.

Comment: And add_subdirectory have a potential problem. If mylib has a target which is the same name as the 3rdlib. Then cmake will crash... So I may need to use command like "cmake -G ..." to compile 3rd first. The it's just like local library. I just need to link to it. If I don't use ExternalProject, what should I do. Can you give me some samples.

Comment: Your app uses code from mylib and mylib uses code from 3rdlib, right? this means that your app eventually uses code from 3rdlib, so it has to be linked to 3rdlib dynamically or statically. And you don't have to compile 3rdlib to link to it. It is enough to have its headers and binaries. CMake can add existing binaries as targets with `add_library(IMPORTED)` command.

Comment: "If mylib has a target which is the same name as the 3rdlib" - it would be better to use another name for your lib target than use `ExternalProject`. But if you insist, here is the simplest form:    `ExternalProject_Add(THIRD_LIB_TARGET
    SOURCE_DIR "${THIRD_LIB_SOURCE_DIR}"`
`BINARY_DIR "${THIRD_LIB_BINARY_DIR}"`
`CMAKE_ARGS` `"-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${PROJECT_INSTALL_DIR}")`

Comment: Thank you for your replay!. I want to add all my dependencies of mylibs. 1. How to use tools to collect all dependency into one package? cpack? Can you give me some examples?
2. How to combine all dependency into my lib. So that I just give others one lib(my lib) and everything's fine.